# Stop hover animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

When cursor is hovered on main span - the animation works fine, but when I remove the cursor from it - the animatioon is still working.

How can I stop it, and why it still going?

```
$('#menu span:first').hover(function (){
  function pulse(){
    // here I have animation
  }
  pulse();
}, function(){
  //Here I tried to set the initial opacity to stop animation
  $('#menu span:first').animate({opacity: '0.5'}, 400);
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/f7RNQ/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use an indicating boolean.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6sXmZ/)

```
$(document).ready(function (){
      $('#menu span:first').hover(function (){
        $('#menu').data('pulsating',true);
        function pulse(){
          if(!$('#menu').data('pulsating')) return;
          $('#menu span:first span').eq(0).delay(100).animate({opacity: '1'},400);
          $('#menu span:first span').eq(1).delay(200).animate({opacity: '1'},400);
          $('#menu span:first span').eq(2).delay(300).animate({opacity: '1'},400);
          $('#menu span:first span').eq(3).delay(400).animate({opacity: '1'},400);
          $('#menu span:first span').eq(4).delay(500).animate({opacity: '1'},400);
          $('#menu span:first span').eq(5).delay(600).animate({opacity: '1'},400);
          $('#menu span:first span').eq(6).delay(700).animate({opacity: '1'},400);

          $('#menu span:first span').eq(0).animate({opacity: '0.3'},400);
          $('#menu span:first span').eq(1).animate({opacity: '0.3'},400);
          $('#menu span:first span').eq(2).animate({opacity: '0.3'},400);
          $('#menu span:first span').eq(3).animate({opacity: '0.3'},400);
          $('#menu span:first span').eq(4).animate({opacity: '0.3'},400);
          $('#menu span:first span').eq(5).animate({opacity: '0.3'},400);
          $('#menu span:first span').eq(6).animate({opacity: '0.3'},400,pulse);
        }
        pulse();
      }, function(){
        $('#menu span:first').animate({opacity: '0.5'}, 400);
          $('#menu').data('pulsating',false);
      });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Read more about the [.finish()](http://api.jquery.com/finish/)

It "Stop the currently-running animation, remove all queued animations, and complete all animations for the matched elements"

```
$('#menu span:first').finish()
```

The other alternative is [.stop( [queue ] [, clearQueue ] [, jumpToEnd ] )](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

```
$('#menu span:first').stop()
```

It "Stop the currently-running animation on the matched elements."

Answer (score 1):

Use `stop(true)`  event

Working fiddle [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/f7RNQ/14/)

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
      $('#menu span:first').hover(function (){
        function pulse(){
          $('#menu span:first span').eq(0).delay(100).animate({opacity: '1'},400);
          $('#menu span:first span').eq(1).delay(200).animate({opacity: '1'},400);
          $('#menu span:first span').eq(2).delay(300).animate({opacity: '1'},400);
          $('#menu span:first span').eq(3).delay(400).animate({opacity: '1'},400);
          $('#menu span:first span').eq(4).delay(500).animate({opacity: '1'},400);
          $('#menu span:first span').eq(5).delay(600).animate({opacity: '1'},400);
          $('#menu span:first span').eq(6).delay(700).animate({opacity: '1'},400);

          $('#menu span:first span').eq(0).animate({opacity: '0.3'},400);
          $('#menu span:first span').eq(1).animate({opacity: '0.3'},400);
          $('#menu span:first span').eq(2).animate({opacity: '0.3'},400);
          $('#menu span:first span').eq(3).animate({opacity: '0.3'},400);
          $('#menu span:first span').eq(4).animate({opacity: '0.3'},400);
          $('#menu span:first span').eq(5).animate({opacity: '0.3'},400);
          $('#menu span:first span').eq(6).animate({opacity: '0.3'},400, pulse);
        }
        pulse();
      }, function(){
        $('#menu span:first').animate({opacity: '0.5'}, 400);
      });
      $('#menu span:first').mouseout(function() {
          $('#menu span:first span').stop(true);
      });
});
```

It means : Here when u do moust out , Stop animating `$('#menu span:first span')`

Comment: Consider using `stop(true)` to clean animation queue, otherwise animation still continues if I hover and remove mouse several times.

Comment: this stops the animation while running, and leaves it in an unfinished state. especially the last animation is not played.

Comment: @lukkysam , so u want animation to be played?

Comment: @jQuery Angry Bird : I think he wanted a smooth effect after leaving the text with the mouse. Perhaps I'm wrong, but it looks nicer imo.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stop()` to finish animation for all child `span` inside first `span`.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
      $('#menu span:first').hover(function (){
        function pulse(){
          $('#menu span:first span').eq(0).delay(100).animate({opacity: '1'},400);
          $('#menu span:first span').eq(1).delay(200).animate({opacity: '1'},400);
          $('#menu span:first span').eq(2).delay(300).animate({opacity: '1'},400);
          $('#menu span:first span').eq(3).delay(400).animate({opacity: '1'},400);
          $('#menu span:first span').eq(4).delay(500).animate({opacity: '1'},400);
          $('#menu span:first span').eq(5).delay(600).animate({opacity: '1'},400);
          $('#menu span:first span').eq(6).delay(700).animate({opacity: '1'},400);

          $('#menu span:first span').eq(0).animate({opacity: '0.3'},400);
          $('#menu span:first span').eq(1).animate({opacity: '0.3'},400);
          $('#menu span:first span').eq(2).animate({opacity: '0.3'},400);
          $('#menu span:first span').eq(3).animate({opacity: '0.3'},400);
          $('#menu span:first span').eq(4).animate({opacity: '0.3'},400);
          $('#menu span:first span').eq(5).animate({opacity: '0.3'},400);
          $('#menu span:first span').eq(6).animate({opacity: '0.3'},400, pulse);
        }
        pulse();
      }, function(){

        $('#menu span').children().stop();
      });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f7RNQ/15/)**